# backbone view and window.getSelection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm having trouble getting window.getSelection to work inside a backbone.js view.

The view works fine otherwise, but whenever I select some text, then click on my test button that triggers the window.getSelection function, the selection always shows as empty.

I figure it may have something to do with my view and the way views attach to the page.

Here is my test code:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'test',
    template: _.template(tmpl, null, { }),

    events: {
        "click .testSelection": "testSelection"
    },

    initialize: {...}
    render: {...}

    testSelection: function () {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            console.log('selection range: ', document.getSelection().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

No matter what I select, I always get this in the console:

*selection range: (an empty string)*

Is there a trick to getting this to work inside backbone.js?

Thanks!

Comment: And you're clicking something to fire the function? Isn't the selection lost when you click something else?

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/mcrh0dnk/ at least on my FF and Chrome

Comment: Yeah I'm clicking a <span> tag with the class name of testSelection. Clicking this fires the function that gets the selection...

Comment: And there's your issue, when clicking the span the selection is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@adeneo is right. Once you click on the  you're effectively destroying the selection range. Nonetheless, there's an easy workaround for your issue: save the original selection. Just adjust the following properties:

```
events: {
    "mouseup": "testSelection",
    "click .testSelection": "getSelection"
},

testSelection: function () {
    this.currentSelection = window.getSelection();
},

getSelection: function() {
    console.log(this.currentSelection.toString());
}
```

The key here is to save the selection. You can do whatever you want with it later (like displaying it in the console on a `<button>` click).

**Note** that I set our view to listen to `mouseup` *anywhere* in the view. If there's only a particular `<element>` (or range of elements, like all `<p>` in the view) that you care about, I would use that element.

You can also check out the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty48w03z/1/).
(Credit to @nikoshr for providing the base fiddle)